# angularjs: UI not updating inside directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the following directive, I do a pretty long running operation, so I want to display a loading spin during that time. I've used ng-show and a isLoading variable on the scope of the directive. However the spinner never shows although isLoading is set to true.

What's wrong with my code ?

```
angular.module('shared.directives').directive("xmlVisualizer", ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div ng-show="isLoading" class="center span10"><i class="icon-spinner icon-6x">chargement du fichier...</i>  </div> <div class="center span10" ng-show="!isLoading"> <h4>Détail du fichier {{title}}</h4> <pre id="test" class="prettyprint"></pre></div>',
    scope: {
        model: '=',
        title: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.model) {
            scope.isLoading = true;

            scope.xml = vkbeautify.xml(scope.model);
            $("#test").text(scope.xml);
            $("#test").html(prettyPrintOne($("#test").html(), 'xml'));

            scope.isLoading = false;
        }
    }
}
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is actually that `isLoading` in the template is not the `isLoading` within the directive, rather it's looking for it in the parent scope. Hence, as it is `undefined` (and stays `undefined`, because you're only changing the `isLoading` inside the directive), it always shows the `!isLoading` block.

You could try to do

```
 template: '<div is-loading="isLoading" ng-show="isLoading" class="center span10"><i class="icon-spinner icon-6x">chargement du fichier...</i>  </div> <div class="center span10" ng-show="!isLoading"> <h4>Détail du fichier {{title}}</h4> <pre id="test" class="prettyprint"></pre></div>',
    scope: {
        model: '=',
        title: '=',
        isLoading: '='
    },
```

but I'm not sure if it would work with a primitive. If not, perhaps try an object `$scope.isLoading = {value: true};` (on the parent scope -- probably the controller) and `is-loading="isLoading.value"` (on the template).

That way, the spinner flag on your controller will get updated through the bi-directional binding, and your directive will be able to use it in its template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch the scope

Try this

```
    angular.module('shared.directives').directive("xmlVisualizer", ['$rootScope',        function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-show="isLoading" class="center span10"><i class="icon-spinner icon-6x">chargement du fichier...</i>  </div> <div class="center span10" ng-show="!isLoading"> <h4>Détail du fichier {{title}}</h4> <pre id="test" class="prettyprint"></pre></div>',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            title: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(function(scope){return scope.model}, function(model){
                if (model) {
                    scope.isLoading = true;

                    scope.xml = vkbeautify.xml(scope.model);
                    $("#test").text(scope.xml);
                    $("#test").html(prettyPrintOne($("#test").html(), 'xml'));

                    scope.isLoading = false;
                }
            })
        }
    }
}]);
```

PS: I am not very  well versed with angular myself. Hope this works for you.

Comment: that does not seem right to me. Why would I watch the entire scope ? and that's not going to update the UI. I've tried scope.$apply() though and it didn't work as there is a digestion in progress already.

Comment: Guess is that you need to watch the scope from inside the link function explicitly. U might consider logging the arguments of your link function to see how many times it's called. Logic would have it that it will be called every single time there is a change in scope but it is actually called only on init or change in the particular html in DOM. No change in scope actually triggers the link function you have written. Also every change in scope will not trigger the second function inside $watch argument. I have deduced all this through console logging. May be not 100% right. Trying to help

Comment: @Sam he's not watching the entire scope, just the model. `function(scope){return scope.model}` is equivalent to `'model'`

Comment: Also I have assumed that change in scope.model needs to trigger everything here. Change if necessary

Comment: @RanjithR, I think using the '=' binding for the model scope variable is enough. I don't need to watch it too. AMOF, my binding works fine. Whenever the model is changed, the UI updates itself. But the loading spinner never shows up, and that I don't understand why. thanks for helping